# Input with submit wont execute If/else statement

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, search

This looks very simple but I cant get it working. Im not experianced in web design but here is the following:

I am trying to make input bar(like search box) that when entered specific text it redirects you to other page or makes somethign else.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
        <form method="post">
            <input id="search" type="text"/>
            <button onclick="return abc()">test</button> 
        </form>
<script>

function abc() {
    var textt = document.getElementById("search"); 
    if (textt.value == "test") {
        window.location.assign("http://www.google.com")
    } 
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uvnyd8vz/1/

this just refreshes page and thats it. Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the value as string
Like 
`textt.value =="test";`
Also inside the function write 
`event.preventDefault();`
This will stop the submit action of submit button
Also specify the else condition i.e.

```
else{return false;}
```

Comment: oh my god thats such a dumb mistake, but fixing that did not fix my problem, it still refreshes page

edit: event.preventDefault(); worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to use `event.preventDefault();`  and in case of else condition `return false`

Comment: Also, when I inplement this code in my main website, it doesnt work and gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined(…)`in console, any ideas?

Comment: Are you using plain JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: Plain js, didint even look into JQuery But it only gives error when I type function in console manualy, If I call that function by submit, it just refreshes page

Comment: This is because when you call the function from console the event object is not the same which you get from click of submit button. Also do not forget to add `return true` at the end of the function

Comment: Or is there any way around? I dont need specifily to use form, I would jsut like to press enter to activate search thing

Comment: I see, but it still does not do anything, just refreshes page. And when I call it from console, I make sure I type word and simulate the button press, also adding return true did not help either. Still same thing

Comment: Yes there is a better way. You can add eventlistener to your body element for keypress event and check the charcode to be 13 then call the search function

Comment: Thats a great idea! I thought I gonna need to use JQuery that is bird lanulage for me. Thanks It will help I think.

Comment: It will be available inside the event object, which you get inside the function

Comment: Im lost. Should It be one line for event listener or should I make seperate function that checks something. Cant find information in web

Answer (score 0):

Adding event.preventDefault(); to function fixed my problem! thanks

Comment: I did, it probobly doesnt show up becasue I dont have 15 reputation yet!